# Google Sheet MATCH formula with multiple criteria always returns 1

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup, index-match

I'm trying to understand the =MATCH() function with multiple criteria.

As far as I understand it binary outputs a 0 or 1 if a criteria is met.
So I would expect in the background for my example the result would be (1,1,0,0)*(0,1,1,0) = (0,1,0,0) so if I then =MATCH(1,(0,1,0,0)) I expect it to return 2 instead of 1.

Can anyone explain where my mistake is?

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yes | yes | no |
|  | yes | yes |
|  | no | yes |
|  | no | no |

`=MATCH(1,(B1:B4=A1)*(C1:C4=A1))`

[example][image: 1]

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster Isn't that what I did?

Comment: To inform you that your email will be public, if you share  spreadsheets. It's a canned response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(1, (B1:B4=A1)*(C1:C4=A1), 0))
```

[image]

you are multiplying arrays so you will need ARRAYFORMULA wrapping and also do not forget on 3rd MATCH argument

Comment: That works. Why is it necessary to add that formula when you are using a MATCH but it isn't necessary when using an INDEX-MATCH?

Comment: @NielAgi INDEX is another type of ARRAYFORMULA and it's interchangeable

Comment: Alright, thanks.
I have a follow up question, should I make a new post for it or just ask it here?
https://imgur.com/a/Ms8UePH

I match where the reviewee name is andy and the rating is 2 so I would expect the match to return "3" but it just returns an entire matrix?

Comment: @NielAgi can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?